# D3 chart on node.js server getting error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js

I am running a d3 chart on node.js server. The server is emitting the data, which i want to display on client. The code on server side is:

```
server.listen(3000, function () {

var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;

dataStream.send("start");

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("Connection set");
dataStream.on('message', function(msg){
    var data = msg.values;
    socket.emit('stream', data);
    console.log(data);
    });
});

});
```

And the data looks like:

```
[ { at: '2014-11-18T07:28:33.859Z', value: 0.553292 },
{ at: '2014-11-18T07:28:23.481Z', value: 0.581186 },
{ at: '2014-11-18T07:28:13.048Z', value: 0.552239 } ]
```

My client code where i want to display "value" on y-axis and time in seconds on x-axis. Am getiing error when i an iterating the data using forEach loop. The client code is:

```
 <title>LineChart with Json Data</title>
    <style>
  .line{
    stroke:steelblue;
    fill:none
 }
 </style>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8">   </script>
<script>
 var message;      
 var socket = io.connect('http://soc'); // soc here is localhost
 socket.on('stream', function (data) {
 console.log("Client:");
 message+= data;
 document.getElementById('viz').innerHTML = "" + message;
 var width = 640;
 var height = 480;
 var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
 width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);     
 var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");    

 var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.xAxis); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.yAxis); })
    .interpolate("linear");

 var vis = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g").attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var iso = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");    
        console.log(message);
     // Am getting error here 


    message.forEach(function(d) {
    d.xAxis = iso.parse(d.at); 
    d.yAxis = parseFloat(d.value); 
});


x.domain(d3.extent(da, function(d) { return d.xAxis; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(da, function(d) { return d.yAxis; }));
vis.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height +   ")").call(xAxis);
vis.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis);

vis.append("svg:path").datum(message).attr("class", "line").attr("d", line);    
      });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <div id="viz" </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You are running `message.forEach`. At that point, what's the type of the `message`? Is it an array or a string? I am not sure why you have it as `message+=data`. But I can't properly run your code right now (`da` is eg. not defined)

Comment: da is message only, sorry for the mistake. message +=data, becoz data is the stream from a device and it is getting updated every 10 sec, i want to display the data of past 1 hr from current time.

Comment: ok, in your example, `data` is an array. Note that maybe the `+=` doesn't have the desired effect on your array (e.g. `a=[1,2,3]; a+=4` results in `"1,2,34"`). Are you sure you don't want to `push`?

Comment: Is this so?, i thought it would work like: a= [1,2,3,4].